# Need to Launch a special version of FireFox from .bat file and use the webdriver for it

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to build an automation test using the Selenium Java for the WebApp designed for a Unit using a special Firefox browser that launches with .bat file. I need to ensure that webdriver will use that special version of Firefox, not the ordinary one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify firefox binary path using `org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary`. See https://www.javatips.net/api/org.openqa.selenium.firefox.firefoxbinary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I decided to use a different approach. I have managed to set up the default firefox to open the desired application.
Now I'm having issues with picking up the firefox profile and proxy.